# In Mongo DB how do I execute the following statement in C#?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In Mongo DB how do I execute the following statement in C#? The C# driver is not converting Linq into aggregation framework,  so I can't use linq. If I use linq it reads all the data from the DB and groups in the application level and which is not making use of New MongoDB aggregation framework. Looks like CommandDocument may be used but I don't find any documentation for that and not sure how to use it.

```
db.orders.aggregate([ 
 { $group: {_id:"$cust_id",total:{$sum:"$price"}} } 
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to the same question that was posted here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/8dM1LnHh9-Q